# Setting up server with multiple routers and static ip

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

Happy new year!

From the title of this post it might seem a very thing to do but still let me explain the whole setup here.

We've two ISP connections with two different routers. One of them has a static IP. Let's call them R1 and R2s (s-static ip). R2s is our backup router, in case R1 is down.

So the primary router is R1 has DHCP enabled. Its output goes to a D-Link 8 port unmanaged switch which has another 8 port switch attached to it. Let's call them S1 and S2. An output S2 from goes to the LAN port of WiFi router (W1). This lets me keep all devices on the same network including those on the WiFi. W1 merely acts as a wireless switch. This network has IP range of 192.168.0.xxx.

Now, our developers want to setup a server using static IP of R2s so that it can be accessed remotely. For this purpose, we changed the internal IP of R2s to 192.168.0.101 so it appears as just any other device to R1 and connected it to the switch S1. The machine which will be made server has been assigned IP: 192.168.0.51 and is connected to the switch S1.

Now, when I hit the static IP of R2s, it should forward that request to 192.168.0.51 and launch the application on the server on the specified port. So, I set it in the NAT. From R2s' admin page, .51 can be pinged but when we try to access it from outside, it doesn't work.

Once again, our network setup is:
R1->S1->R2s/S2/W1.
Where exactly should I add this route to be able to access it?

Please help.

TIA
swap

Comment: You haven't mentioned anywhere about port forwarding so when you hit your R2s "public IP" the request is forwarded to your server so it can give you the output you desire....

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "1-1 NAT Mapping" set up so that R2 is accessible via it's WAN IP?
From what I can gather, you have simply given it a LAN IP and connected it behind R1?
So how does R1 know what to do with a request that comes in for R2's WAN IP?
Assuming that requests hitting R2's WAN IP are getting through to R2, then you need to set up Port Forwarding for whichever port you are planning to use, to the target machine on .51, as Big Chris mentioned.

Comment: I've setup port forwarding inside R2s so that when its WAN IP is entered, it forwards that request to .51. R2s is basically an ADSL router which gets its internet connectivity from ADSL line and LAN is the output port. The reason I'm connecting R2s as a slave to R1 is that I don't want to route internal traffic through internet.

Comment: Before worying about portforwarding to devices behind R2, you need to make sure that R2 can be reached on its WAN IP. If I'm readign your reply correctly, you still haven't set anything up to tell R1 how to forward traffic addressed to R2's WAN IP (the one given by your ISP). Also, since R2 is a "backup" connection, is your ISP actively/concurrently routing traffic to its static IP, or are they only activating the connection when R1 is down?